# React Native navigation bar within modal

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I want to have a Modal which contains a navigation bar, purely for styling, not so much functionality. This means I do not want to have different routes.

I tried this:

```
<Modal visible={true}>
  <NavigationBar title={<Text>{'This is a Modal'}</Text>} />
</Modal>
```

as well as this:

```
<Modal visible={true}>
  <NavigationBar title={<Text>{'This is a Modal'}</Text>} />
</Modal>
```

Both bring about errors. The first attempt had the error: `Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got undefined` and the second attempt: `'undefined is not an object (evaluating navState.routeStack)'`.

I'm assuming that I cannot add a navigation bar unless a specify add the `<Navigator>` component too, which seems like a waste since I don't require it's functionality, only the styling of the navigator.

Any ideas on how to add a navigation bar to a modal? Thanks.

Comment: NavigationBar doesn't support that usage, see https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/CustomComponents/Navigator/NavigatorNavigationBar.js#L54

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a library to achieve what I wanted: [React-Native-Navbar](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-navbar)